# Dynamic number of sliders

Tags: php, jquery, symfony1, slider, symfony-1.4

I need to create a page that has "n" number of sliders on it.

It concerns soccer player profiles retrieved from a database.
I'm using "carouFredSel" to make the sliders, but I can't make it work with an undefined amount of sliders (I hope I'm being clear enough).

Here is an example...

```
foreach($sports as $sport):
  <div class='sportContainer'>
  foreach($players as $player):
   <div class='playerInfo'>
   </div>
  endforeach
  </div>
endforeach
```

Here is the script I used for displaying other kinds of players (just one slider per page):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        /* PLAYER SCROLL */
        $('.sport-carousel').carouFredSel({
            items: 4,
            prev: '.title-prev#playersNav',
            next: '.title-next#playersNav',
            auto: false,
            scroll: 1,
            swipe: {
                ontouch : true,
                onMouse: true
            }
        })
    });
```

I need each $sport to have its own slider, with its own controls and listing-button.
In other words, I need the identifier to be obtained dynamically.

Here is the [carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) page for more info.

I'm using Symfony 1.4 for the project, if that helps in some way.

Comment: So when you tried to add multiple elements with a class of `.sport-carousel` and then run that code against them, what happens?

Comment: The number of items refers to the number of playerInfo divs, correct?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if i create multiple elements with that class, they just scroll all at the same time with the controllers, i forgot to put the `.title-nav` div that contains the scroll-controls, they refer to a single script (the one i pasted in the question).

Comment: @Ken Hannel that's correct, btw i need to reference the nav controls to a script so each slider beheave independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've made it through, creating a script foreach sport was the deal.

```
foreach($sports as $sport):
  <div class='sport-carousel_$sport->getId()'>
  foreach($players as $player):
   <div class='playerInfo'>
   </div>
  endforeach
  </div>
$(document).ready(function() {
        /* PLAYER SCROLL */
        $('.sport-carousel_$sport->getId()').carouFredSel({
            items: 4,
            prev: '.title-prev#playersNav_$sport->getId()',
            next: '.title-next#playersNav_$sport->getId()',
            auto: false,
            scroll: 1,
            swipe: {
                ontouch : true,
                onMouse: true
            }
        })
    });
endforeach
```

Thanks for the help, hope it works for creating sliders dinamically

Answer (score 1):

Just use some jQuery to count the number of items.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        /* PLAYER SCROLL */
        $('.sport-carousel').carouFredSel({
            items: $('.playerInfo').length,
            prev: '.title-prev#playersNav',
            next: '.title-next#playersNav',
            auto: false,
            scroll: 1,
            swipe: {
                ontouch : true,
                onMouse: true
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: If you have many carousels on one page you can count the items for each carousel: `$(this).find('.playerInfo').length`

Comment: items: are equal to the number of items in 1 carousel, that means, `.lenght` will only count the items belonging to 1 Slider, i need to get a dinamic selector to call a dinamic amount of sliders.
I have an undefined amount of sports = i need an undefined amount of sliders.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong, Items are equal to the amount of `.playerInfo` to show in the slider box, i mean the amount of players to see, i've set 4 items so 4 players are shown and then scroll the rest by one (scroll)